# Kotlin, Image Upload with retrofit take to long

Tags: laravel, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

i am trying to upload image from android app to laravel server.

and i am using @waqas7 method from link below
https://github.com/waqas7/UploadImageOnServer

problem is, file is to big and take to long. is there another way to upload the file ? like changing it's format to something encoded and smaller
and i am a web developer mostly so if you can answer with detail that would be fantastic
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone that may got this problem i use a compress method to decrease the size

```
private fun compressImage(sourceImageFile: File): File? {
    val destinationFile = context?.getDestinationFileForImage()
    try {
        val timeToExecute =
            destinationFile?.let { CompressImage.compressImage(sourceImageFile, it) }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
    return destinationFile
}

object CompressImage {

fun compressImage(sourceFile: File, destinationFile:File):Long{
    return measureTimeMillis {
        val currentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sourceFile.absolutePath)
        currentBitmap.compress(
            Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
            CompressFileUtils.COMPRESS_QUALITY,
            FileOutputStream(destinationFile)
        )
    }
}
}
```

also you lose the orientation so you need to save it before compressing the image

```
    val attributes = arrayOf(
        ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME,
        ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME_DIGITIZED,
        ExifInterface.TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME,
        ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH,
        ExifInterface.TAG_FOCAL_LENGTH,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_ALTITUDE_REF,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_DATESTAMP,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_PROCESSING_METHOD,
        ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_TIMESTAMP,
        ExifInterface.TAG_MAKE,
        ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL,
        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
        ExifInterface.TAG_SUBSEC_TIME,
        ExifInterface.TAG_WHITE_BALANCE
    )

        val oldExif = ExifInterface(file)
        oldExif.getAttribute(attributes[16])
        exifData1 = oldExif.getAttribute(attributes[16])
```